# improve php function random string

Tags: php, function, random, unique

I have function, which generates a random string. It's ok but I want to generate unique numbers, this function returns generated numbers again.

```
function getRandomString($length){
$validCharacters = "12345678910";
$validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);
$result = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $index = mt_rand(0,$validCharNumber - 1);
        $result .= $validCharacters[$index];
    }
return $result;}

$x= getRandomString(2).substr(time(),-4);//rand(1000000,9999999);
```

Comment: If you have a function that will never return the same number again then it isn't a random number generator...

Comment: no this function returns some numbers again i want not return, (sorry for bad english)

Comment: The only way to do this is to keep track of all the numbers you've generated before and try generating a number until you've hit one which hasn't been generated before. There's other solutions but overall this isn't what random is supposed to do.

Comment: Are you looking for unique numbers?

Comment: Timpo, yes I want unique generated numbers

Comment: @GochaGochitashvili Unique for this session or unique from now to the end of time?

Comment: you can try with uniqid() function

Comment: I have registration form, this function allow me to generate random invoice numbers after submit form, but I  see same generated numbers again

Comment: Don't do this. You can, but the cost will greatly outweigh any benefit (you'll have to keep track of what you've generated). Either use a string which is long enough for it to be very unlikely to generate the same numbers or look into using an auto-incremental number to generate the next number.